# Run a controller or service as a variable

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have a service called `MyService.js` with `MyAction` exported, which can be called anywhere as

```
MyService.MyAction()
```

I need to call it as a variable. The following works

```
var myAction = "MyAction"

MyService[myAction]()
```

However, is there a way to use the same logic for the service name as well? For example:

```
var myAction = "MyAction"
var myService = "MyService"

myService[myAction]()
```

I believe this should be run using the `sails` object, but I don't know where to start.

Is there anything like:

```
sails.services[myService][myAction]()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with the sails object, I found a solution.

In order to call a service as variable, you need to make sure the service name is in lowercase, since how Sails store them. Apparently the actions keep their original case, so they are case sensitive.

```
var myAction = "MyAction"
var myService = "MyService"

sails.services[myService.strToLower()][myAction]()
```